# PHP time add hours error

Tags: php

I try to add hours to the server time but when I tried a tutorial I got a confusing time.

Code:

```
$timestamp = time();
$datum = date("d.m.Y",$timestamp);
$now = date("H:i",$timestamp);
//Actual Week Day
$dw = date( "w", $timestamp);
echo $datum," - ",$now," oclock "," Weekday ",$dw; 
//Add hours to server time
$timeadd = date("H:i", strtotime("+ 8 hours",$now));
echo " Time add = ", $timeadd;
```

And this is the output:

> 05.12.2015 - 20:55 oclock Weekday 6 Time add = 09:00

Why is the output from Time always 09:00 ?

Comment: I tried it, works well for me...

Comment: mhm I have this on a VServer from 1&1 here is the link http://phpmailer.s18447150.onlinehome-server.info/email.php

Comment: http://randume.org/testscrpts/stackoverflow.php

Comment: Check the PHP version...

Comment: I have the version 5.3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
$timeadd = date("H:i", strtotime("+ 8 hours",$now));
```

needs to be:

```
$timeadd = date("H:i", strtotime("+ 8 hours",$timestamp));
```

I think you're confusing strtotime with what you're passing in, it just needs the raw timestamp that you got at the beginning with time().

Comment: Hey this returns "05.12.2015 - 21:37 oclock Weekday 6 Time add = 08:47"

Comment: I'm also getting the right return: 05.12.2015 - 14:45 oclock Weekday 6 Time add = 22:45

Comment: hold on let me check something

Comment: ok ignore all of what we just talked about and check my revised answer lol

Comment: let me know if you're still having problems

Comment: I think the Problem is the PHP version and i try to install a newer but centos support only 5.3

Comment: in my test it was giving me an unpredictable time with $now and the correct time when I used $timestamp

Comment: mhm no i try it in 1-2h the php update destroy my plesk i must first reinstall the server....

Comment: Just checked, this answer helps.